# How to retrigger kernel and initramfs generation in Debian upgrade process

Tags: dist-upgrade

I did a Debian 10 to 11 upgrade process and everything went fine. Before doing the reboot, I lost the config, initrd, System.map and vmlinuz files in the boot partition.

Unfortunately, repeating apt-get full-upgrade does not retrigger the process of regenerating these files.

Due to the peculiarity of the system booting into LiveCD is no option. I should find a way to retrigger the generation of these 4 files from the system which currently is still booted into Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get --reinstall <kernel-name>` did the trick